# For matlab, I have an array with 5 sentences, and I need to find the number of special characters in each sentence

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, character, conditional-statements

So my code for this is:

```
my5Sentences={'Windows machines are better than Macs.','The Intel core i7 4770k is a great processor.','My email is rjoshi8@drexel.edu','I go to Drexel','I am writing this in MATLAB & and I am writing this code for Engr-180'};
for i=1:length(my5Sentences)
 fprintf('The total number of characters in this sentence is %i\n',length(my5Sentences{i}))
end
```

This part of the code displays how many characters are in each sentence, but now I need to find out how many special characters are in each sentence. I am not sure what the code for this would look like. By the way, thanks to PearsonArtPhoto for helping me out with the original question.

Comment: Use `regexp`: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

Try regular expressions:

```
[f]=regexp(my5Sentences{i},'([^a-zA-Z_0-9\s])','tokens')
```

check the other outputs of f if you need indices, and the documentation of regexp if some caracters are treated wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html):

```
>> cellfun(@(str) numel(regexp(str, '\W')), my5Sentences)

ans =

     6     9     5     3    16
```

I'm assuming "special character" means anything other than a letter or number. Otherwise, change the `'\W'` to whatever you need. For example, if spaces and periods don't count as special characters use

```
cellfun(@(str) numel(regexp(str, '[^a-z_A-Z0-9\s.]')), my5Sentences)
```

Comment: I think the asker is from the same class as the other guy!  Hahah!